# Geodesics are minimizing in a simply connected manifold without conjugate points?

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $\tilde M$ be a compact Riemannian manifold, without conjugate points. Denote by $M$ its universal cover. Then in [this paper](http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/conjugate.pdf), it is claimed that every geodesic is globally length minimizing.

Why is this true?

Is it true for any simply connected manifold without conjugate points, or the fact $M$ is a universal cover of a **compact** manifold plays a role?

---

Note: If $M$ is not simply connected, than the lack of conjugate points does **not** imply geodesics are minimizing. (For example look at the cylinder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it is the universal cover of a compact manifold is not essential, what you need is completeness of the Riemannian manifold $\tilde M$ (the universal cover of a compact manifold is always complete) and its simple connectivity. Assuming these two properties and the NCP property, just follow the proof of the Cartan-Hadamard theorem to conclude that for each $p\in \tilde M$ the exponential map $\exp_p: T_p \tilde M\to \tilde M$ is a diffeomorphism. From this, you see that any two points are connected by a unique geodesic. This implies that geodesics are global length minimizers.

Comment: Thanks. Of course you are right... somehow I did not think about this.