# Uniqueness of minimizing geodesic $\Rightarrow$ uniqueness of connecting geodesic?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Let $M$ be a complete connected Riemannian manifold. Fix $p \in M$.

Assume **every** point in $M$ has a **unique minimizing** geodesic connecting it to $p$. Is it true that for every point, the **only** geodesic connecting it to $p$ is the minimizing one?

(Does the answer change if we count periodic geodesic as one?)

---

**Remarks:**

(1) In all the examples I have checked so far this holds. Of course, if for **some** $q \in M$ there is a unique minimizing geodesic, it does not imply there is a unique geodesic from $p$ to $q$ (think of a circle).

For spheres,tori,cylinders - the claim vacuously holds, since there is no point satisfying the hypothesis (every point has an "antipodal" point where there is more than one minimizing geodesic).

(2) **If the assertion is true**, it implies something quite strong on manifolds where minimizing geodesics are always unique; By [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1530064/104576) such a manifold must be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ (via at the exponential map).

Actually, one can adapt the argument of that answer to see that **if there is one such point $p$** (that minimizing geodesics from it to all other points are unique), then the manifold will be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Thus, *to refute the conjecture*, it is enough to find a manifold with *one* such point which is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to section 4 of [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.mmj/1029004750):

Stephanie B. Alexander, I. David Berg, and Richard L. Bishop, Cut loci, minimizers, and wavefronts in Riemannian manifolds with boundary, Michigan Math Journal, Volume 40, Issue 2 (1993), 229-237

for a connected complete Riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ **without boundary** the cut-locus $C(p)$ of a point $p\in M$ equals the closure of the set $N(p)$ consisting of points $q\in M$ such that there is more than one minimizing geodesic between $p$ and $q$.

Now, your assumption is that $N(p)=\emptyset$ for **some** $p\in M$. Hence, $C(p)=\emptyset$ for this $p\in M$. Thus, according to the answer to your earlier question (I think you asked this question several times, I remember writing an answer), it follows that any point in $M$ is connected to $p$ by a unique geodesic as $\exp_p$ is a diffeomorphism.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking into the paper now. By the way, this is the question you have answered before: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1612453/geodesics-are-minimizing-in-a-simply-connected-manifold-without-conjugate-points (It is different from the current question and from the one on manifolds with globally minimizing geodesics). Also, note that here I only assumed $N(p)=\emptyset$ for *one fixed* point $p$, not for every $p \in M$. However, it does not change the conclusion, since in this case, for this specific $p$, $\text{exp}_p$ will be a diffeomorphism...

Comment: (This essentially follows from the answer to the global minimizers question).

Comment: No, the OP's assumption is not that $N(p) = \emptyset$ for every $p$. The OP's assumption is that *there exist* $p \in M$ such that $N(p) = \emptyset$. From this, indeed, one may use the result that you cite to conclude that $C(p) = emptyset$. Since, in general, $\exp_p$ gives a diffeomorphism between $M \setminus C(p)$ and some open subset of $T_p M$, it follows here that $M$ is diffeomorphic to a star-shaped open subset of $\Bbb R^n$, hence to $\Bbb R^n$.