# Uniqueness of geodesic imply no conjugate points?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Let $M^n$ be a manifold diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R^n$, equipped with a complete Riemannian metric $g$. Suppose for any two points $p, q \in M$, there exists one and only one geodesic connecting $p$ to $q$. Does this imply that $g$ has not conjugate points? 
ps. the reverse is true.

Comment: See my answer http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1865210/uniqueness-of-minimizing-geodesic-rightarrow-uniqueness-of-connecting-geodesi?rq=1 and the reference there.

Comment: @Seub , I assume the manifold is diffeomorphic to $R^n$. So "no conjugate points" implies uniqueness of shortest geodesic connecting two points.

Comment: @Seub, thanks, I change the way of written.